# Regex that matches lines with a leading or trailing asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need to match every line that starts or ends with a single asterisk character without any other asterisk in between.

```
1.- foo BAR, FOO1*

2.- *FOO, bar% foo

3- *foo). BAR", fOo*

4.- **foo BAR foo

5.- *foo bar foo**

6.- foo bar * foo

7.- foo bar foo
```

I want to match the lines number 1 to 3, the other lines I won't match them.

My aproach:

```
^[\*](?:[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-\s])|^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'+/=?^_`{|}~-\s]+.\*$
```

but doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/5 corrected

Comment: you regExp does not contain line num. 3

Comment: it does if you checked the updated one, or what am I missing? I should not have deleted the leading `1. - ` parts? Thats part of the strings?

Comment: @Eraklon The leading '1.- , 2.-...'  parts aren't part of the string, is the number lines for the example.  It's working fine!!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: You say above: "I need to match every lines (sic) that starts or ends with a single asterisk character" but in the examples you provide, we can deduce that there are more conditions. Shouldn't it be more correct to say: "I need to match every line that starts or ends with a single asterisk character without any other asterisk in between"?

Comment: @PierreFrançois The character class used by the OP also would not match an asterix.

Comment: If you don't mind, I will edit your question as I proposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why such a complication? Try:

```
(^\*[^*]*\*?$|^[^*]*\*$)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/oOCSE5/6

Basically, you have two cases `(`*first case*`|`*second case*`)` of matches expressed in the regex above:

1. A string starts with a asterisk `^\*`, contains no asterisk `[^*]*`, and ends with one or zero asterisk `\*?$`
2. A string doesn't contain any asterisk `^[^*]*` except the last char `\*$`

Comment: look like it should fail if there is * in the middle of the string, which is valid..

Comment: @CristianTraìna: the solution you propose doesn't match the third line of input, i.e. a line starting **and** ending with an asterisk.

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky: an asterisk in the middle is not valid. See input line 6 above: no match allowed.

Comment: input like `*kkk*kk` should be valid

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky: we should have to ask to the PO. Since `**kkkkk` is not valid, I suppose `*kkk*kk` is not valid.

Comment: I not see your logic.. the condition defined as `starts or ends with a single asterisk character`

Answer (score 0):

In the case you do not need any asterisk in the middle of the string as well - use `Pierre François` answer.

In the case an asterisk is accepted in the middle of the string try this:

```js
var tests = [
"foo BAR, FOO1*",
"*FOO, bar% foo",
'*foo). BAR", fOo*',
"**foo BAR foo",
"*foo bar foo**",
"foo bar * foo",
"foo bar foo"];

var regex = /(^\*(?!\*).*(?<!\*)\*?$)|(^\*?(?!\*).*(?<!\*)\*$)/;


tests.forEach(t => console.log(regex.test(t)));
```

Comment: I get: `"message": "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group",`.  Be aware that lookbehind is not supported by all browser. This shouldn't be used in production.